# My Visual Studio Code won't render on Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, visual-studio-code, ide

This is how it looks:

[image: pic]

Can anyone fix this problem?

Answer (score 1):

Try running   `code --disable-gpu`

There is a discussion on GitHub about this issue: https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/161681

Comment: nope. this is probably not it.